# Appium Client app problem for start inspection or start testing

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Here's the steps of problem I am facing:

**Predefined: My Android SDK path and JDK path has been given in config section. Also "Session override" is checked **

- I'm opening the Appium Client.
- Starting the server.
- Starting"Inspector session" Choosing the previously saved device with capatalities.
- Choosing automatic server.
- Trying to start thesession.
- After sometime, I'm ending seeing this message:

***Error
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: zipAlignApk failed. Original error: spawn EPERM. Stdout: 'undefined'; Stderr: 'undefined'***

The capabilites I've provided:

1. {
2. "deviceName": "",
3. "platformName": "",
4. "platformVersion": "",
5. "appPackage": "",
6. "appActivity": ""
7. }

Note: I have used appium desktop in same pc before... But somehow seeing this message now... In between, I've done several Android Studio installation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L09YM.jpg)

Comment: Did you pass empty capabilities?

Comment: No no... I passed the required value ... Here I just mentioned the names of capabilities.

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes, I am on windows.

Comment: Try running it with administrator privileges